# C++ compiler error definition-implicitly declared

Tags: c++

Hello everyone having anissue with my code today. I have created a program to help me understand different c++ Constructors, With a base class ABC. .

So far have gotten far in my code yet in my ABC.cpp file am getting an error on line 10 that says ABC.cpp:7: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'ABC::ABC(const ABC&)

ABC.cpp code :

```
#include "ABC.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    ABC::ABC(const ABC & a) : ptr(new int(*(a.ptr)))
        {cout <<" Constructeur de Recopie "<< endl;}

    ABC::ABC(int x =0) : ptr(new int (x))
        {cout <<"Constructeur" << endl;}



    bool ABC::operator == (ABC c)
        {return (*ptr == *(c.ptr));}



      ABC::~ABC(){
          delete ptr;
      }
```

ABC.h

```
#ifndef ABC_H_INCLUDED
#define ABC_H_INCLUDED

class ABC {

    int * ptr;

public:

    ABC (int x = 0);
    ABC ( const ABC& );

    bool operator == (ABC c);

    ~ABC();



};


#endif // ABC_H_INCLUDED
```

Error on this line :

```
ABC::ABC(const ABC & a) : ptr(new int(*(a.ptr)))
        {cout <<" Constructeur de Recopie "<< endl;}
```

Comment: I would have expected an error saying that you cannot repeat the default value `= 0` in the definition.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that code, but I don't see anything that would give that error message, and it compiles for me, with warnings.

Comment: What is the single closing curly brace `}` doing there in the .cpp?

Comment: @alain It closes the definition of the destructor. Beautiful.

Comment: @LogicStuff oh yes. Maybe I should un-learn to use the indentation to "parse" the code..